# How to set linearLayout as a content(setContent) and call in the same method

Tags: android

I am trying to do a Timetable which a user have to select their subjects and their subjects will be displayed in another activity.
I wish to put them in a TabHost like "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri";
And I wanted to call my result(User's subjects selection) in the same activity (View Timetable) but I don't know how.
Please help me

ChooseSubject.java
This is where user can select their subject, and when they click "See Your TimeTable".
It will call the "ViewTimetable.java" and show result in tabhost

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChooseSubject extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

SQLiteDatabase db;
String[] dbSubject = {
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (1,'TPRG343','Introduction to Android Programming')",
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (2,'TNWK343(L)','Network Security(Lectural)')",
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (3,'TNWK224(L)','System Administration')",
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (4,'TWEB334','Advanced Web Design')",
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (5,'TWEB224','Web Programming')",
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (6,'TNWK343(T)','Network Security(Tutorial)')",
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (7,'TMMD233','Multimedia Presentation')",
        "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (8,'TMMD113','Computer Graphics Editing')"

};

String[] dbTimetable = {
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (1,'Monday','8.30am - 11.30am','KKL','B106')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (2,'Monday','12.30pm - 2.30pm','GBS','B103/B302')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (3,'Monday','3.00pm - 6.00pm','GBS','B103/B302')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (3,'Friday','4.30pm - 6.00pm','GBS','B103/B302')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (4,'Tuesday','12.00pm - 1.30pm','KKL','B106')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (4,'Thrusday','10.00am - 1.00pm','KKL','B101')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (5,'Tuesday','2.00pm - 4.30pm','YKC','B101')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (5,'Friday','12.00pm - 2.30pm','YKC','B101')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (6,'Tuesday','4.30pm - 6.00pm','GBS','B103/B207')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (7,'Wednesday','9.00am - 12.00pm','YKC','B101')",
        "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (8,'Thrusday','1.30pm - 4.30pm','Widura','B101')"

};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_subject);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("subjects", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("Create table if not exists subjects (id integer primary key, subCode text, subName text)");
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from subjects", null);
    //Access for the first time,
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dbSubject.length; i++) {
            db.execSQL(dbSubject[i]);
        }
    }
    db.execSQL("Create table if not exists timetable (id integer, day text, time text, lecturer text, class text)");
    Cursor ttCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from timetable", null);
    //Access for the first time,
    if (ttCursor.getCount() == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dbTimetable.length; i++) {
            db.execSQL(dbTimetable[i]);
        }
    }

    String sId, sCode, sName;
    String output = "";
    Cursor spCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from subjects", null);

    Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(spCursor.getCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (spCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (spCursor.moveToNext()) {
            //output = spCursor.getString(spCursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + " \n" + spCursor.getString(spCursor.getColumnIndex("subName"));
            output =  spCursor.getString(spCursor.getColumnIndex("subName"));
            subjects.add(output);
        }
        //
    }

    final LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    Button btnTt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seeTt);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    btnTt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent =  new Intent(ChooseSubject.this,ViewTimetable.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Build an AlertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChooseSubject.this);


            final boolean[] checkedSubjects = new boolean[subjects.size()];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < subjects.size(); i++){
                checkedSubjects[i] = false;
            }

            // Convert the array to list
            //final List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

            String[] subjectsOutput = new String[subjects.size()];
            subjectsOutput = subjects.toArray(subjectsOutput);
            final ArrayList<String> selectedItem = new ArrayList<String>();
            //final List<String> subjectList = Arrays.asList(subjects);

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(subjectsOutput, checkedSubjects, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    // Update the current focused item's checked status
                    checkedSubjects[which] = isChecked;

                    if(isChecked){
                        selectedItem.add(String.valueOf(which));

                        db.execSQL("Create table if not exists UserSubject (subName text)");
                        String query = "insert into UserSubject values   ('"+ selectedItem + "');";
                        db.execSQL(query);
                    }
                    else {
                        selectedItem.remove(String.valueOf(which));
                    }

                    // Get the current focused item
                    String currentItem = subjects.get(which);

                    // Notify the current action
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            currentItem + " " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Specify the dialog is not cancelable
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            // Set a title for alert dialog
            builder.setTitle("Choose your subjects");

            // Set the positive/yes button click listener
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click positive button
                    tv.setText("Your subjects are \n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedSubjects.length; i++) {
                        boolean checked = checkedSubjects[i];
                        if (checked) {
                            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n" + subjects.get(i) + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Set the neutral/cancel button click listener
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click the neutral button
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            // Display the alert dialog on interface
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_choose_subject, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

ViewTimetable.java

```
package com.example.win81.newera;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class ViewTimetable extends ActionBarActivity {

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        String id, subCode, subName, day, time, lecturer, myClass;
        String outputTime, outputMon, outputTue, outputWed, outputThur, outputFri;
        LinearLayout layout,box;
        TextView tvTime,tvDetail;
        TabHost tabHost;

        ArrayList<String> MondaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> TuesdaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> WednesdaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ThrusdaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> FridaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_timetable);

            layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.liLayout);
            tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

            TabHost.TabSpec mon = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
            TabHost.TabSpec tue = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
            TabHost.TabSpec wed = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third Tab");
            TabHost.TabSpec thu = tabHost.newTabSpec("Forth Tab");
            TabHost.TabSpec fri = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fifth Tab");

            mon.setIndicator("Mon");
            tue.setIndicator("Tue");
            wed.setIndicator("Wed");
            thu.setIndicator("Thu");
            fri.setIndicator("Fri");



            db = openOrCreateDatabase("subjects", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                    "select s.id, subCode, s.subName, day, time, lecturer, class" +
                    " from subjects s, timetable t, UserSubject us " +
                    "where s.id = t.id and us.subName = s.subName",null);


            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    box = new LinearLayout(this);
                    box.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    //box.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    //layoutParams.setMargins(35, 10, 35, 10);
                    tvTime = new TextView(this);
                    tvTime.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                    tvDetail = new TextView(this);

                    //box.addView(tvDay);
                    box.addView(tvTime);
                    box.addView(tvDetail);
                    box.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    layout.addView(box);

                    id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    subCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode"));
                    subName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName"));
                    day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("day"));
                    time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));
                    lecturer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"));
                    myClass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class"));

                    if(day.equals("Monday")){
                        outputMon = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer")) ;
                        outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                        tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                        tvDetail.setText(outputMon);

                        mon.setContent(new Intent(, ViewTimetable.class));
                    }

                    if(day.equals("Tuesday")){
                        outputTue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                        outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                        tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                        tvDetail.setText(outputTue);
                    }

                    if(day.equals("Wednesday")){
                        outputWed = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                        outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                        tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                        tvDetail.setText(outputWed);
                    }

                    if(day.equals("Thursday")){
                        outputThur = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                        outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                        tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                        tvDetail.setText(outputThur);
                    }

                    if(day.equals("Friday")){
                        outputFri  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                        outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                        tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                        tvDetail.setText(outputFri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_timetable, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```